# How can I add branch or commit details to a bamboo WAR

Tags: grails, bamboo

I use bamboo to build my Grails WARs. It published it as an artifact.  I insert the bamboo build number.  I would really like to also insert the branch, the plan and even the git commit somewhere into the WAR.  Any ideas how I could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know two plugins which can provide some build information:

- [build-info](http://grails.org/plugin/build-info)
- [build-info-tag](http://grails.org/plugin/build-info-tag)

For solving your situation, I think may want to look into `writeBuildInfoFile(path)` method [here](https://github.com/fterrier/grails-build-info-tag/blob/master/scripts/_Events.groovy)